does Krishna support the notion of the Jiva BECOMING Krishna as opposed to just REACHING him?
There are many examples of deities getting equated to the Jiva:
In which scriptures are the verses ''aham brahmasmi" and ''shivoham'' found?
Does any work say 'Vishnuraham' - I am Vishnu like there is 'Shivoham' - I am Shiva?
The Sarvamedha yagna also said to allow the Jiva to become Brahman.
The Upanishadic statements like Tat Tvam Asi say that the Jiva is the same as Brahman.
This Q is based on R Prasanna' comment

Even in Vaishnavism there is achintya abheda and vasista advaita, who identify the jivas or souls equal to lord himself in moksha state.. whereas bhagavdgita states about reaching god only, never ever gives assurance the jivas are equal to lord himself or jivas become god, there is no statement of bhagavad gita to support this –
Prasanna R
Commented8 hours ago

under the question
What does Gita Chapter 7 Verse 23 mean?
If this is true - it would give support to the idea that Bhagavad Gita a Dvaita scripture.

Short Answer: The Bhagavad Gita or Lord Krishna is in favor of Vaishnavism. Lord Krishna never states that the Jivatma will become Krishna upon attaining Moksha and start enacting Leelas such as lifting the Govardhan Hill, etc.
Long Answer:
As stated in the Vedic aphorisms such as Tat Tvam Asi and Aham Brahmasmi, Jiva is eternally Brahman. The Abheda in the Achintya Bheda-Abheda Tattva denotes this eternal nature of the Jivatma.
This liberated state of those who attain Moksha is denoted by Lord Krishna through the words मद्भ‍ावं (My nature) in Chapter 8 Verse 5 (Translations used are by AC Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada).

अन्तकाले च मामेव स्मरन्मुक्त्वा कलेवरम् ।
य: प्रयाति स मद्भ‍ावं याति नास्त्यत्र संशय: ॥ ५ ॥

And whoever, at the end of his life, quits his body remembering Me
alone at once attains My nature. Of this there is no doubt.

In this state of Abheda, the Muktatma can either remain in that state of perpetual bliss of Sri Bhagavan's nature or accept a state of qualified-dualism and engage in His devotional service.
This is not the dualism of the Baddhatma (conditioned soul) in forgetfulness of his identity as Brahman and/or making occasional prayers before a Deity, nor is this Abheda or perpetual bliss attained by the Muktatma by remembering Krishna the same as the worship of the non-dual truth.
The Gita discusses both Bheda as well as Abheda provided their definitions are in line with those of Lord Krishna and Arjuna.
In Chapter 12, when asked by Arjuna, Lord Krishna speaks about the worship of that which is akṣaram (beyond the senses), anirdeśyam (indescribable), and avyaktaṁ (unmanifest) which is essentially non-dualism.

अर्जुन उवाच
एवं सततयुक्ता ये भक्तास्त्वां पर्युपासते ।
ये चाप्यक्षरमव्यक्तं तेषां के योगवित्तमा: ॥ १ ॥

Arjuna inquired: Which are considered to be more perfect, those who
are always properly engaged in Your devotional service or those who
worship the impersonal Brahman, the unmanifested?
श्रीभगवानुवाच
मय्यावेश्य मनो ये मां नित्ययुक्ता उपासते ।
श्रद्धया परयोपेतास्ते मे युक्ततमा मता: ॥ २ ॥

Sri Bhagavan said: Those who fix their minds on
My personal form and are always engaged in worshiping Me with great
and transcendental faith are considered by Me to be most perfect.

Krishna further explains that even those who engage in the worship of that which is akṣaram anirdeśyam avyaktaṁ (non-dual truth) at last attain Him, but never become Him. This is denoted through the words ते प्राप्‍नुवन्ति मामेव

ये त्वक्षरमनिर्देश्यमव्यक्तं पर्युपासते ।
सर्वत्रगमचिन्त्यं च कूटस्थमचलं ध्रुवम् ॥ ३ ॥
सन्नियम्येन्द्रियग्रामं सर्वत्र समबुद्धय: ।
ते प्राप्‍नुवन्ति मामेव सर्वभूतहिते रता: ॥ ४ ॥

But those who fully worship the unmanifested, that which lies beyond
the perception of the senses, the all-pervading, inconceivable,
unchanging, fixed and immovable – the impersonal conception of the
Absolute Truth – by controlling the various senses and being equally
disposed to everyone, such persons, engaged in the welfare of all, at
last achieve Me.

In the above verse, it can be seen that Lord Krishna does not reject the worshippers of the non-dual conception of the Absolute Truth and in fact calls them as those who control their senses, are equally disposed to everyone, and work for the welfare of all living entities. However, He states that they also ultimately attain Him.
Hence, the Bhagavad Gita favors Vaishnavism more than any other philosophy.
